# Show list projects that I join in

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 3 tables:

```
Employee: contain employee_id, name

Project: contain project_id, name
Project_assignment: contain id_assign, employee_id, project_id, startdate, enddate
```

I want to show list projects that I joined with info: name_project (I joined), the number of people join in the project, and startdate( the date when I join in project)

Is there anyway to do that? Thanks

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Firstly, I try to get list project_id I join in, then with them I can count the number of people join in the project. But I have problem with getting start_date of project that I join in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT P.Project_Id, P.Name as ProjectName, PA.StartDate, COUNT(E.Employee_Id) as EmployeeCount
FROM Project P
   JOIN Project_Assignment PA ON P.Project_Id = PA.Project_Id
   JOIN Employee E ON PA.Employee_Id = E.Employee_Id
GROUP BY P.Project_Id, P.Name, PA.StartDate
```

Note, assuming employees joined the project on different days, this won't give you unique records.  If this is the case, which start date would you want to show?

--EDIT

This should return you the projects you are in (assuming your id is 123), along with the project id, project name, start date, and count of employees:

```
SELECT P.Project_Id, P.Name as ProjectName, PA.StartDate, E.EmpCount
FROM Project P
   JOIN Project_Assignment PA ON P.Project_Id = PA.Project_Id AND PA.Employee_Id = 123
   JOIN (
       SELECT Project_Id, Count(Employee_Id) EmpCount
       FROM Project_Assigment
       GROUP BY  project_id
   )
   E ON P.Project_Id = E.Project_Id
```

Good luck.